# Using symbols in sympy with Polygon

Tags: python, sympy, symbols

I'm trying to determine if a pt is inside a polygon. The pt has to be entered as a symbol due to its integration with other part of the code. However, I realised that I can't evaluate the result. I got a "NoneType". My code is:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import Symbol, Piecewise, lambdify, And, Ne
from sympy import Point, Polygon

x1, y1 = Symbol('x1'), Symbol('y1')
x2, y2 = Symbol('x2'), Symbol('y2')

xp, yp = Symbol('xp'), Symbol('yp')

p1, p2, p3, p4 = map(Point, [(0, 0), (5, 0), (5, 5), (0,5)])

poly = Polygon(p1, p2, p3, p4)

isEnclosed = poly.encloses_point(Point(xp, yp))
isi = lambdify([xp,yp], isEnclosed, "numpy")

xp_act = 2
yp_act = 1

is_act=isi(xp_act,yp_act)

print(is_act)
```

Can someone help?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the `lambidify` is doing anything useful.  But if you want to stick with it, show the **full error, with traceback**!

Comment: `poly.encloses_point(Point(xp, yp))` returns `None`, it does not create a mathematical expression to test whether `xp,yp` are inside the polygon. For arbitrary polygons, you can't just write a simple expression.

Answer (score 0):

Your `isEnclosed`, as @JohanC points out, is `None`.  Wrapping that in `lambdify` doesn't change that.

```
In [30]: isEnclosed = poly.encloses_point(Point(xp, yp))
In [31]: isEnclosed
In [32]: isi = lambdify([xp,yp], isEnclosed, "numpy")
In [33]: isi(2,1)
```

`help(isi)` displays:

```
_lambdifygenerated(xp, yp)
    Created with lambdify. Signature:
    
    func(xp, yp)
    
    Expression:
    
    None
    
    Source code:
    
    def _lambdifygenerated(xp, yp):
        return None
```

Using specific pairs of numbers:

```
In [35]: isEnclosed = poly.encloses_point(Point(2,1))
In [36]: isEnclosed
Out[36]: True
In [37]: isEnclosed = poly.encloses_point(Point(2,100))
In [38]: isEnclosed
Out[38]: False
```

`lambdify` isn't just a wrapper that lets you "call" a sympy expression with an array. It tries to translate the expression into a python/numpy function.  It can handle things that are `numpy` equivalents.  There isn't such an equivalent for this `poly` module.

Comment: ok, i got it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function that allows you to input values for x and y and get a result you can do so like this:

```
>>> p = Polygon((0, 0), (5, 0), (5, 5), (0,5))
>>> isin = lambda x, y: p.encloses_point((x,y))
>>> isin(1,1)
True
>>> isin(-1,-1)
False
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: yes, it working! i'll see if i can somehow use this form of expression in the code. Thanks!